# how to do a regexp validation for us phone number not to begin with 0 or 1?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, phone-number

I've been looking at many regexp validations for phone numbers but I could not find one that allows only 10 digits and not to start with 0 or 1, obviously only numbers

I found this one

```
^((\+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-\s\.])?((\(\d{1,4}\))|\d{1,4})(([-\s\.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}$
```

but is to allowing for what I need.

I am using this expression in javascript and I can use the max 10 digits there.

any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

10 digits, not starting with 0 or 1:

```
^[2-9]\d{9}$
```

Quick explanation:

```
^       start of string
[2-9]   matches only digits 2 to 9 (thus excluding 0 and 1 as requested)
\d{9}   any 9 digits
$       end of string
```

Comment: But hey, it's not 100 chars regex! :) +1

Comment: Yeah doesn't need to for such simple request ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 input boxes for phone number and wanna test the first box, use the same regexp suggested by @m0skit0...

```
/^[2-9]\d{2}$/.test(phone_field_1.val())
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you see my solution with 10 digits. 
Important: They don't start with 0 or 1 !!!

```
^[2-9]\d{9}$
Further explanation:

^       beginning of string
[2-9]   matches only digits 2 to 9 (NOT 0 and 1 as I mentioned above)
\d{9}   any 9 digits
$       end of string
```

I hope I could help you!

Comment: Did you just copy-paste my answer? :O